# Passing class by value

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift so please let me know if I've missed something painful obvious. I have a `class` that I want to pass by value to overload the `+` operator.

The code won't work if I define the left argument `lhs` as `foo` but then it is immutable, and will work if `lhs` is `inout foo`, but then I have modified `lhs` which I clearly do not want.

A quick breakdown of my class:

```
class foo<T: Numeric> {
    /* Data */
    /* Init Fn */
    /* += definition */
    static func + (lhs: foo, rhs: foo) -> foo {
        do {
            try lhs += rhs
            return lhs
        } catch {
            /* Error Handling */
        }
    }
}
```

I come from a C++ background, so I am surprised that I am unable to pass the object by value if I choose. Following the question [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading), in C++ this overloading method would expect the left argument to be passed by value and the right argument to be passed by `const &` as shown below, but here I don't seem to have that option.

```
class X {
    /* In Swift operators are not defined internally like this */
    X& operator+=(const X& rhs) {
        // actual addition of rhs to *this
        return *this;
    }
};
inline X operator+(X lhs, const X& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Is there a way that I don't know about, or is overloading done differently in Swift?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to do `y += x` without modifying `y`? What would the expected result of such an operation be?

Comment: I want to modify `y` locally in the function rather than modify its reference.

Comment: In C++ you can decide to allocate classes on the stack. In Swift all classes leave in the heap. You just cannot pass a class as a value. I would argue it's C++ with the obscure lvalue & rvalue rules, not Swift. You should start by defining `+=` using `+`, not the other way around.

Comment: I don't understand the question: What are you hoping to achieve by passing an object instance by value? Are you trying to make `+` return a modified copy of `lhs`, rather than mutating the existing instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any real problem with mutability. Note that with classes, without passing-by-value, you just cannot use one operator to define the other one.

```
class Foo<T: Numeric> {
    var value: T

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    static func + (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Foo {
        return Foo(value: lhs.value + rhs.value)
    }

    static func += (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) {
        lhs.value += rhs.value
    }
}

let ten = Foo<Int>(value: 10)
let eighteen = ten + Foo<Int>(value: 8)
eighteen += Foo<Int>(value: 1)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, great! In C++, its the other way round: the `+` operator is defined by the `+=` operator, which I guess is why I have been struggling. How strange!

Comment: @Z4ckZ3r0 I was thinking about structs actually. I have corrected the reasoning. The problem is that you cannot use one operator to define the other one because in one you are creating a new object while in the second you are mutating an existing object. With value types this would not be a problem.